# Invalid initializer member declarator when using model in controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to make a standard menu which has MAIN MENU item and inside it comes SUB MENU items like this. I am using MVC 5. When I use my model inside controller then I get this error `Invalid initializer member declarator`. Menu will be something like:

### Home

Link1
Link2

### About

Link3
Link4

Following is my model class:

```
namespace MyWebsite.Models
{
    public class SubMenu
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public Uri Link { get; set; }
    }

    public class MenuModel
    {
        public string MainMenu { get; set; }
        public List<SubMenu> sMenu { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And here's my controller code:

```
public ActionResult MakeMenu()
{
      var menu = new List<MenuModel>
      {
            new MenuModel
            {
                  MainMenu = "Home",
                  new List<sMenu> //getting error on this line that 'Invalid initializer member declarator'
                  {

                  }
            },
            new MenuModel
            {
                  MainMenu = "About"
            }
      }.ToList();

      return View(menu);
  }
```

Why am I not been able to `sMenu` this way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sMenu` is not a `Type` to be used as generic type parameter `T` in `List<T>`;
`sMenu` is just the property on your `MenuModel`.
Its `Type` is `SubMenu`.

It should be:

```
var menu = new List<MenuModel>
{
    new MenuModel
    {
          MainMenu = "Home",
          sMenu = new List<SubMenu> {},               
    },
    new MenuModel
    {
          MainMenu = "About"
    }
}.ToList();
```